# QuickBooks Item Query help needed

Tags: quickbooks

I'm sure this is going to be a long shot, but I need help with a query involving QuickBooks Items.

I need to query for all QuickBooks Items that are linked to an Income account. Is there an easy way to do this, or do I need to make 2 queries (one for items ans one for accounts) and then check the account reference?

albeit not much, I have this:

```
IItemQuery query = MsgSetRequest.AppendItemQueryRq();
```

any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should provide more details on which version, SDK, language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use at least two queries. You'll need to fetch a list of accounts, and then compare the items AccountRef FullName to the income accounts in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Using the XML, at least, if you query all items you can get back the accounts of all of them, and filter for the account that you want. The full name of the account will be included in the item query response if you specifically ask for it in IncludeRetElement.